# Poisson Binomial Distribution Moments

Tags: statistics

I'm carrying out a piece of work where we are trying to approximate the distribution and parameters of a problem where we assume there are a fixed number of insurance policies y, each of which has a fixed sum assured (money paid on claim). Each person holding a policy has an identical probability of death (q). Therefore what is the distribution of the total claims in a year.

Letting the total claims in a year be T and I be the indicator random variable binomially distributed with n of 1, prob of success (claim) of q, and Si being the sum assured per policy, the total is then:

$T = \sum_{i=1}^{y} I_i S_i$

I know that it will be normally distributed (at least approximates) due to CLT, with:

$E[X]=yq \sum S_i$

But I cannot begin the derivation of the variance of the underlying distribution. I have run monte carlo simulations and compared the variance with what I think it could be (typically binomial).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- For an individual, the payout is $S_i$ with probability $q$ and $0$ with probability $1-q$
- From this you can find the expected payout for that individual, and the variance of the payout for that individual
- The expected total payout is the sum of the payouts for the individuals
- If the claims are independent then the variance of the total payout is the sum of the variances of the payouts for the individuals

Comment: Hey there. Agreed. Unfortunately we only get the data at the homogeneous group level. I.e. the total sum assured for all individuals with the same rate q, we are then expected to use a Poisson binomial to sum these across the entire company.

I was planning on doing it the way you have noted, but I cannot doing this as we do not have the sum assured per policy, only the total for all individuals with the same q. I was just wondering if perhaps they just gave us this data, because deriving the distribution of the whole group results in only needing the data summarised at the group level.